# Creating a dynamic table from AJAX reply query

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I have the following code:

```
            var htmlname='';
            var names = result.names
            $.each(names, function( i, name){

               htmlname = "<td>" + name + "</td>";

               $('#adminall tr:last').html(htmlname);

                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                var tableCurrentPoints = document.getElementById("adminall"); // find table to append to
                tableCurrentPoints.appendChild(row); // append row to table


            });


            var htmlemail='';
            var emails = result.emails
            $.each(emails, function( ii, email){

               htmlemail = "<td>" + email + "</td>";

               $('#adminall tr:last').html(htmlemail);

                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                var tableCurrentPoints = document.getElementById("adminall"); // find table to append to
                tableCurrentPoints.appendChild(row); // append row to table


            });
```

And then the table which its appending too:

```
        <table id="adminall" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr id="adminallheader">

        </tr>
        <tr></tr>

    </table>
```

This is from a success handler within an AJAX request. I am attempting to create a table populated with the data from the query, and I'm guessing it should be created in Javascript as I am attempting here, but I can't get it to work. At the moment it has all the data (name and email) in one column, but it needs to be split across the two.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like

```
       var names = result.names
       $.each(names, function( i, name){
           //get the corrsponding email
           var email = result.emails[i];
           var htmlname = "<td>" + name + "</td><td>"+email"</td>";

           $('#adminall tr:last').append(htmlname);

            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            var tableCurrentPoints = document.getElementById("adminall"); // find table to append to
            tableCurrentPoints.appendChild(row); // append row to table


        });
```

and loop only once and not twice.

Comment: Since he's using jQuery, I would suggest replacing those document.createElement and document.getElementById calls.

Comment: @Meryovi no i left those because they have less overhead that using a jQuery function (which in the end would call those functions anyway)

Comment: Ok thanks @NicolaPeluchetti!! My only concern is... I am designing it in such a way that the user ticks checkboxes for the columns they want to receive in the query. The back end stuf for that is all done, but the way youve shown above relies on the user ticking the names checkbox. I am thinking of having a seperate value passed through JSON which is a mysql_num_rows value which is used to iterate the loop. Does that sound ok to you? and then IF statements within the loop to determine whether or not to show the column headers/values...